# How to only keep the first two digits of a string?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I have been trying this but it's not working :

```
function twonumbers(num)
    num = tostring(num):gsub("%d%d(.*)","")
    return num
end
```

Basically it's for making a seconds counter using os.clock()

Also tried to make one that only keeps two digits after the dot :

```
function twodigits(num)
    num = tostring(num):gsub("%.%d%d(.-)","")
    return num
end
```

I feel like i'm using gsub wrong.

Comment: I don't think you need patterns here. You could use `math.floor()` on the number `os.clock()` gives you. Example: http://ideone.com/FE4diV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question directly: just use `string.match`

```
function first_two_digits(str)
    return str:match("^%d%d")
end
```

But, you don't need to do this at all, just use math operations:

```
math.floor(os.clock())
```